# Suggestions for Statistical Analysis

Tags: correlation, statistical-significance, anova, inference

So I have this special project that had me evaluating for the levels of heavy metals in the surface soil and subsoil at the dumpsite in my local community. I've done all the experimental work already, and I have raw data for the concentrations of the metals in the surface and subsoil (8 sites, 2 samples per site surface and sub, total of 16 soil samples with 3 replicates for each sample). I also have raw data for other soil parameters like pH, percent moisture and  percent organic matter, same 3 replicates each.

Statistically, I was thinking of looking into whether there are significant differences between the different sites and differences between topsoil and subsoil as a whole. Also going to need to correlate the concentrations to the other parameters mentioned.

Anybody have any suggestions into the statistical analysis that I could do?

Comment: The concentrations of substances in the soil, especially near the surface at waste sites, are notoriously variable. It is irreducible spatial variability; the replicates are of little help. You would be lucky indeed to see any clear patterns from soils sampled at just eight locations.  There's no way a correlation analysis of these data will yield significant results.  Focus, therefore, on characterizing mean (or geometric mean) concentrations and expect to achieve little more. *Maybe* you can detect a mean difference between depths.

Comment: Understood. Going to go at it from the depths perspective then. How about any correlations I could do between concentrations and the soil parameters I mentioned?

Comment: Also note that percent moisture is likely to vary significantly in *time* (i.e. in the [near-surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vadose_zone)).

Comment: @whuber - So how would I go about interpreting the geometric mean of the concentrations? Do you mean the mean concentrations per site or for the whole set of data?

Comment: The entire set of data. It might help to understand the measurement procedure. Typically, one obtains about a kilogram of soil. This is preserved and shipped to the lab, which extracts a "subsample" of a few grams. This is digested and processed into a small drop of liquid, which is what gets analyzed. Often, when the subsample-extract-measure procedure is repeated in the lab, large variation is observed (especially for anthropogenic compounds or in areas where soil has been imported or graded). Thus, even the mean of replicates at one location may say little about the overall area.